# numpy array: fast assign short array to large array with index

Tags: python, numpy

I want to assign values to large array from short arrays with indexing. Simple codes are as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def assign_x():
    a = np.zeros((int(3e6), 20))
    index_a = np.random.randint(int(3e6), size=(int(3e6), 20))
    b = np.random.randn(1000, 20)
    for i in range(20):
        index_b = np.random.randint(1000, size=int(3e6))
        a[index_a[:, i], i] = b[index_b, i]
    return a

%timeit x = assign_x()
# 2.79 s ± 18.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I have tried other ways which may be relevant, for example `np.take` and numba's `jit`, but seems the above is the fastest way. It can also be possibly speed-up using `multiprocessing`. I have `profile` the codes, the most time is at the line below as it runs many times (20 here)

```
a[index_a[:, i], i] = b[index_b, i]
```

Any chance I can make this faster before using `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Often a few iterations (20 is few) on a complex task is fastest, especially when dealing with large arrays.  You might gain some speed by switching everything around so that the  iteration dimension, 20, is first (rows).  But I haven't tried timings.

Comment: While `b[:,i]` is relatively small (1000), `b[index_b, i]` is larger, 3e6.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried your first comment, by changing, e.g., `a = np.zeros((20, int(3e6)))`, 20 to be the first axis, so the assignments become `a[i][index_a[i]] = b[i][index_b]`. 30% improvement is achieved, to `1.82 s ± 5.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, my `b` is very small. I separated the assignments `a[index_a[:, i], i] = b[index_b, i]` to `bk = b[index_b, i]`, then `a[index_a[:, i], i] = bk`. The latter caused more times (> 50%). Seems indexing of large array is not a good idea. But I'm not sure what I can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why this is slow

This is slow because **the memory access pattern is very inefficient**. Indeed, random accesses are slow because the processor cannot *predict* them. As a result, it causes expensive **cache misses** (if the array does not fit in the L1/L2 cache) that cannot be avoided by prefetching data ahead of time. The thing is **the arrays are to big to fit in caches**: `index_a` and `a` takes each 457 MiB and `b` takes 156 KiB. As a results, access to `b` are typically done in the L2 cache with a higher latency and the accesses to the two other array are done in RAM. This is slow because **the current DDR RAMs have huge latency** of 60-100 ns on a typical PC. Even worse: this latency is likely not gonna be much smaller in a near future: the RAM latency has not changed much since the last two decades. This is called the [Memory wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall). Note also that modern processors fetch a full **cache line** of usually 64 bytes from the RAM when a value at a random location is requested (resulting in only 56/64=87.5% of the bandwidth to be wasted). Finally, *generating random numbers is* a quite *expensive* process, especially large integers, and `np.random.randint` can generate either 32-bit or 64-bit integers regarding the target platform.

### How to improve this

The first improvement is to prefer indirection on the most contiguous dimension which is generally the last one since `a[:,i]` is slower than `a[i,:]`. You can **transpose the arrays** and swap the indexed values. However, the Numpy transposition function only return a **view** and does not actually transpose the array in memory. Thus an explicit copy in currently required. The best here is simply to **directly generate the array so that accesses are efficient** (rather than using expensive transpositions). Note you can use simple precision so array can better fit in caches at the expense of a lower precision.

Here is an example that returns a transposed array:

```py
import numpy as np

def assign_x():
    a = np.zeros((20, int(3e6)))
    index_a = np.random.randint(int(3e6), size=(20, int(3e6)))
    b = np.random.randn(20, 1000)
    for i in range(20):
        index_b = np.random.randint(1000, size=int(3e6))
        a[i, index_a[i, :]] = b[i, index_b]
    return a

%timeit x = assign_x()
```

The code can be improved further using **Numba** so to run the code in parallel (one core should not be enough to saturate the memory because of the RAM latency but many core can better use it because multiple fetches can be done concurrently). Moreover, it can help avoid the creation of big temporary arrays.

Here is an optimize Numba code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import random

@nb.njit('float64[:,:]()', parallel=True)
def assign_x():
    a = np.zeros((20, int(3e6)))
    b = np.random.randn(20, 1000)
    for i in nb.prange(20):
        for j in range(3_000_000):
            index_a = random.randint(0, 3_000_000)
            index_b = random.randint(0, 1000)
            a[i, index_a] = b[i, index_b]
    return a

%timeit x = assign_x()
```

Here are results on a 10-core Skylake Xeon processor:

```
Initial code:                  2798 ms
Better memory access pattern:  1741 ms
With Numba:                     318 ms
```

Note that parallelizing the inner-most loop would theoretically be faster because one line of `a` is more likely to fit in the last-level cache. However, doing this will cause a race condition that can only be fixed efficiently with atomic stores not yet available in Numba (on CPU).

Note that the final code does not scale well because it is *memory-bound*. This is due to 87.5% of the memory throughput being *wasted* as explained before. Additionally, on many processors (like all Intel and AMD-Zen processors) the [write allocate cache policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies) force data being read from memory for each store in this case. This makes the computation much more inefficient raising the *wasted* throughput to 93.7%... AFAIK, there is no way to prevent this in Python. In C/C++, the write allocate issue can be fixed using low-level instructions. The rule of thumb is **avoid memory random access patterns on big arrays like the plague**.

Comment: Thanks. Never thought about the memory problem. One fix, for new version of numba, no attribute `range`, so `nb.range` should be `nb.prange`.

Comment: What is `'float64[:,:]()'` in `nb.njit` used for? I removed that part, just kept `parallel=True`, got 2.28 secs. Why so huge difference?

Comment: `'float64[:,:]()'` is the signature of the function. `float64` is the item's type and `[:,:]` means that this is a 2D array. Parameter types are put in the parenthesis but there is no parameters here. Without the signature, Numba compile the function lazily when the function is executed for the first time. This is why it is slower: the compilation time is included in the measured time. I fixed the `nb.range`. Thank you.